# Passing data to view in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the following code

```
    $input = Input::all();
    $this->agro->create($input);

    $alldata = $this->agro->all();

    return View::make('agro.showdata',['myalldata'=>$alldata]);
```

Here when I return `$alldata`, all data from database is displayed.I guess here all the data is stored in `$alldata` variable which we are passing to the `showdata` view file in the variable `myalldata`.

Now when in `myalldata`, if data is not accesses it works as

`<h1>DIsplaying data </h1>`

But when I try to display data, it gives error `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`
ie

```
<h1>Displaying data from database<h1>

{{ $myalldata->title }}
```

Please help display the data from database.

Another thing, every time something is wrong, it gives error `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`How to debug laravel to know where things are going wrong?

Comment: My first reaction was "I bet myalldata is an array, so you'd have to access the first title with `$myalldata[0]->title` or something like that". What happens when you do that?

Comment: From config folder and according to your environment, select environment folder then find app.php, set 'debug' => ture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that $myalldata is an array of elements. To access each one, you'd need to use a for-loop, like such, in your view:

```
@foreach($myalldata as $row)
    <div>{{{ $row->title }}}</div>
@endforeach
```

---

You can determine whether to display the full error trace by modifying your application's app/config/app.php file, and replacing

```
'debug' => false,
```

with

```
'debug' => true,
```

Keep in mind that, in a production environment (when clients can access the site), you'll want to disable debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

> How to debug laravel to know where things are going wrong?

Go to your config/app.php or config/yourEnvironment/app.php and set Application Debug Mode to true.

```
'debug' => true,
```