# Creating a loop to display data from database Laravel, and pass data to next view?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

new to laravel and just wanted to get some tips on how to do the following.

So the view will show all created assignments (using for each i believe) that are stored in my database on PHPadmin. I want to be able to select one of these assignments and pass the assignment ID (name to the next view).,

Thanks

Comment: Try something, post what you tried and then we will help you. [@each](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#rendering-views-for-collections).

Comment: Yes you should show your efforts before asking. By going through the laravel official doc you should be able to come up with some code.

Comment: @Tim, check out this post [Passing data to view in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415634/passing-data-to-view-in-laravel?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

On your blade file:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr onclick="window.location='{{route('user.edit', ['id' => $user->id])}}'">
    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->age}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

On your route file:

```
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController', ['as' => 'user']);
```

Comment: This answer may be helpful, but consider adding a brief explanation to help the original poster and future visitors understand how it works. Thanks.